# Hive: UDF and GROUP BY

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a UDF (GetUrlExt) that returns extension. (ex: jpg in /abc/models/xyz/images/top.jpg).
The data is like shown below:

```
Date Time TimeTaken uristem  
9/5/2011 0:00:10 234 /abc/models/xyz/images/top.jpg  
9/5/2011 0:00:11 456 /abc/models/xyz/images/bottom.jpg  
9/5/2011 0:00:14 789 /abc/models/xyz/images/left.gif  
9/5/2011 0:00:16 234 /abc/models/xyz/images/top.pdf  
9/5/2011 0:00:18 734 /abc/models/xyz/images/top.pdf  
9/5/2011 0:00:19 654 /abc/models/xyz/images/right.gif  
9/5/2011 0:00:21 346 /abc/models/xyz/images/top.pdf  
9/5/2011 0:00:24 556 /abc/models/xyz/images/front.pdf  
9/5/2011 0:00:26 134 /abc/models/xyz/images/back.jpg
```

The query without 'GROUP BY' is working fine:

```
SELECT GetUrlExt(uristem) AS extn FROM LogTable;
```

Result:
*jpg
jpg
gif
pdf
pdf
gif
pdf
pdf
jpg*

Now I need 'GROUP BY' on the results of the GetUrlExt UDF.
Expected Result:
*jpg 3 274.6

gif 2 721.5

pdf 4 467.5*

But the following query is not working:

```
SELECT GetUrlExt(uristem) AS extn, Count(*) AS PerCount, Avg(TimeTaken) AS AvgTime FROM LogTable GROUP BY extn;
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pls use subquery to group by.

Hive doesn't support group by calculated value directly.

```
SELECT a.extn, Count(*) AS PerCount, Avg(TimeTaken) AS AvgTime 
FROM
(
    SELECT GetUrlExt(uristem) AS extn, TimeTaken
    FROM LogTable 
) a
GROUP BY a.extn;
```

Comment: You can group by a calculated value, just not able to use the column alias on which the function has been [applied](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-GROUPingandSORTingonf%2528column%2529). So could specify `GROUP BY GetUrlExt(uristem)`, but the subquery is probably better.

Comment: Thanks, both worked with no much difference in the execution times.

Answer (score 1):

You can either enable group by alias, or you need the whole statement in group by

```
SELECT GetUrlExt(uristem) AS extn, Count(*) AS PerCount, Avg(TimeTaken) AS AvgTime 
FROM LogTable 
GROUP BY GetUrlExt(uristem);
```